# Connecting to a SQL Server with SQL Server Managament Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have looked everywhere on Stack Overflow and I have not found an answer that closely compares to my scenario, so please bear with me.

The issue is I was recently given a development server at work and I have to migrate my current project (which I have on SQL Server Management Studio running on SQL Server Express) so that it is hosted on that server. I was just given the server name and authorized access to it. So I *can* connect to it through Remote Desktop Connection (RDC), but I am clueless as to where to go from here.

I have tried going in through RDC and opening Management Studio from there but when plugging in my server name and using Windows Authentication it doesn't let me in. And I can't use SQL Server Authentication because I'd have to be actually in to be able to create an SQL login.

How can I connect to this server through Management Studio?

Comment: Can you ping the sql server box from your RDC ?

Comment: Very confusing what your current state is. You say "you can connect to it through RDC", but then you later say "it doesn't let you in". What's the issue? Error messages would definitely help...

Comment: I can connect through RDC but once I am inside RDC and I try to connect to the server _through SQL Management Studio_ it doesn't let me in. RDC works, SQL Management Studio doesn't seem to recognize the credentials.

The server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, and it gives me the computer name, full computer name, and domain.

Comment: You should ask the person that installed your server to log into the sql server and give permission to your windows user or create a sql user for you

Comment: Just ask you boss what (s)he wants you to do.

Answer (score 0):

The server is in the same network? In the management studio, in server name, you can put a IP address or computer name.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. My project is currently running on a local version of SQL Express and this server is a dev cloud hosted by the company

Comment: Hablas español? Debes migrar tu base de datos a un servidor remoto, pero no te puedes conectar?

Comment: Si, me puedo conectar por RDC al servidor pero no he logrado conectarme por medio de Management Studio. Quiero poder hacer una tabla y subir filas pero no me deja entrar todavia.

Comment: Para que puedas conectarte desde tu Management Studio a un servidor remoto por SQL Management, el servidor remoto tiene que tener habilitada las conexiones remotas (viene deshabilitado por defecto en SQL Server, aparte debes abrir puertos en el servidor). Si entras por RDC y abres el SQL Management Studio, deberías conectarte poniendo Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if SQL is even installed on the server you are tasked to deploy to? You are able to "connect" to SQL Express locally because the instance is installed on your local machine. You will need an instance of SQL installed on the remote machine to be able to use SSMS to connect to the remote instance.

Comment: SQL Express is not installed on the server. But Microsoft SQL Server is (including Management Studio). Should I install SQL Express? Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of having a dev-server and not depending on SQL Express capacity limitations?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to connect to an already created DB that you have been using the credentials are the same, if you know the address and you have the ports opened on your computer to allow the connection. If you are going to start a new DB on the server, then you will have to connect via AD credentials **IF** your admin has given you the proper access. I personally suggest using AD credentials to create connections, it's just a lot more secure.

If you are trying to connect to the local db, then it should be on the drop down list on the log in screen.

You are going to have to talk with your admin who set it up if you are still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to Enter your Server Details in the Hosts File on the Current Application Server

For Accessing Hosts File,

Go to Run and type drivers and Hit Enter. Go to the etc Folder and you will see hosts file in the Folder.
At the End of the File Enter the Server IP And Server Name
Save the file and try Logging into the Server Management Studio again

Hopefull, this would help